# Recordset that returns an item at a given index?

Tags: php, html, mysql, dreamweaver

Okay, so I currently have a school project which is based on making a website. On my main page I have a "last news" section. I want the news in this section to update whenever a new item is added to my database. The news section contains three divs where I want my three newest database items to be added. Normally I would do this by writing the following SQL code:

```
SELECT carName
FROM cars
ORDER BY carName DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

However the three divs where I want the newest items to go, are separated. And by using this method they wouldn't be separated. I do not have a lot of knowledge on either PHP or SQL. Our curriculum is based 100% around using dreamweaver and PHPMyAdmin to manage our site (I do however know how to use HTML and CSS).

My question is:

Is there a way to make three different recordset which only returns the item at f.ex. the second index? If this was possible I could simply place the return values in the three divs.

What I use to make my site:

Dreamweaver

WAMP (PHPMyAdmin).

Comment: You query all 3 then you loop through the record set and output a div and a record, etc... Or fetch 1 row and output it then later on fetch another row, etc...